# Error: "package com.tumblr.remember does not exist." while building the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

While building the app The Error is....

/Users/amit/Desktop/ANDRO/communup-app/app/src/main/java/com/communup/general/MyApplication.java
Error:(25, 27) error: package com.tumblr.remember does not exist
/Users/amit/Desktop/ANDRO/communup-app/app/src/main/java/com/communup/activities/profile/ShowProfileFragment.java
Error:(38, 27) error: package com.tumblr.remember does not exist
/Users/amit/Desktop/ANDRO/communup-app/app/src/main/java/com/communup/activities/resource/IndexFragment.java
Error:(36, 27) error: package com.tumblr.remember does not exist
/Users/amit/Desktop/ANDRO/communup-app/app/src/main/java/com/communup/general/MyService.java
Error:(31, 27) error: package com.tumblr.remember does not exist
/Users/amit/Desktop/ANDRO/communup-app/app/src/main/java/com/communup/helpers/DateHelper.java
Error:(6, 27) error: package com.tumblr.remember does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 7.565 secs
>   Information:6 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console
>   Please help me to resolve this Issue.....

Comment: do you have added the dependency in your build.gradle file from your app?
https://github.com/tumblr/Remember

Comment: How I can add this? Please guide.

Comment: In Android Studio on the left side you can see on bottom Gradle Scripts
expand this and open build.gradle (Module: app)
look on my second post this is better formatted

Comment: Error:(42, 31) error: package com.twitter.sdk.android does not exist is also an error to solve, Please suggest the resolution for this.

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android#download
I think you should learn more about gradle and dependency management in general
just search for gradle tutorials or look at:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-gradle--cms-22978

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio on the left side you can see on bottom Gradle Scripts
expand this and open build.gradle (Module: app)

In the dependencies area you can declare all your dependencies to other projects:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    /* add here your dependency */

    // from github readme this should be the right 
    compile (group: 'com.tumblr', name: 'remember', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
}
```